# How to add rows from a json (arrays of dicts) in a dataframe already existing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

hi i have already a dataframe:
df_init with all column:

```
A|B|C|D
```

i receive a json like:

```
json=[{"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3"},
{"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4"},
{"A":"1","B":"2"}]
```

i want to have df_final like:

```
A|B|  C |D
1|2|  3 |None
1|2|  3 |4
1|2|None|None
```

if i do:

```
msgJSON=self.spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json_string],1)
            df = self.sqlContext.read.option("multiLine", "true").options(samplingRatio=1.0).json(msgJSON)
```

but i have some problems with error.

thanks

Comment: Want to share those problems? I tried copying and pasting your code but it didn't work because I don't have the minimal example to reproduce your mysterious errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json = [{"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3"},
        {"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4"},
        {"A":"1","B":"2"}]

msgJSON = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json],1)
df_final = sqlContext.read.option("multiLine","true").options(samplingRatio=1.0).json(msgJSON)

df_final.show()
+---+---+----+----+
|  A|  B|   C|   D|
+---+---+----+----+
|  1|  2|   3|null|
|  1|  2|   3|   4|
|  1|  2|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+
```

I replicated your code without keyword `self`. You cannot use `self`, "everywhere".

- For more information, refer: [The self variable in python explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)